# Deep Freeze simulation

Tags: malware

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.1 on my desktop. I wonder if I could create a similar environment as Deep Freeze on my computer by creating a new user with Standard permissions. Let me explain: With the Spectre insecurity discovered, if I were to use my computer as a standard user and some kind of malware installs itself on my system, by erasing the standard user account, would that restore my system to where it was before the malware installation if I login now as an administrator?

Comment: [LTSP](http://ltsp.org/) server and your machine as client may be a solution. Rootfs will not change between boots as it loads everytime from server. Files in home folders will stay.